# AWS route subdomain to s3 static hosting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

Lets say I have a hosted zone - hostabc.com and have an SSL Acm on that hosted zone.

1. I created a S3 bucket name **static-site** with static hosting - static-site.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com.
2. I create a subdomain - static.hostabc.com and route the alias to the S3 bucket

However when I access to some of the assets static.hostabc.com/style.css. The address url wasn't set SSL on it. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Assuming *.hostabc.com:*/* is allowed you shouldn't have any issues but if so, maybe try routing a proxy with the certs applied to the port (sub-domain) you're trying to setup. You can force HTTPs with redirect too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unfortunately, you can't use an SSL certificate with an S3 static website and a custom domain.**

I would recommend using AWS CloudFront to handle this. You can point your sub domain to the CloudFront Distribution, which in turn resolves to your S3 static website. You can associate a CloudFront Distribution with an SSL certification in ACM.

Comment: Is there a guideline to associate a CloudFront Distribution with an SSL certification in ACM?

Comment: @Iverson when creating a CloudFront Distribution, you will have the option to select a custom SSL certificate stored in ACM.

Comment: How tos - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/  and https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-https-requests-s3/